# Cannot play song on Heroku using Discord.js

Tags: heroku, discord.js

I cannot play music with my bot on Heroku today, its written in Discord.js.
But I can play music very well at yesterday, I don't know what happened.(No any info in console)
At first I thought it was an error in my code. I changed the code to the previous version and the error appeared again...

I am using Node js 15 (14 has this issue too, already tried to use Node js 14)
Discord js fork by Matte(I don't think it's Djs's problem)
Heroku free dyno
discord-ytdl-core 5.0.0 with ytdl-core 4.4.4(Lasted)

Comment: Please provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably haven't installed the FFMPEG Buildpack for Heroku. This allowed me to play music on my bot.

If your bot can play locally and not on Heroku, this may be the solution for you:

Below is the link that gives you information on what this buildpack does.
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest